Trigger on insert for each new record
I have a table with this structure
ITEM_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
COST1 FLOAT NOT NULL,
COST2 FLOAT NOT NULL,
PRICE1 FLOAT NOT NULL,
PRICE2 FLOAT NOT NULL,
VALID_FROM DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
VALID_UNTIL DATE NULL,

The default value for VALID_UNTIL is '2099-12-31'
I need to create a trigger in this table so that when I insert new records the most recent record in the table updates the value of VALID_UNTIL to be the same as the value of VALID_FROM of the record being inserted as long as ITEM_ID is the same. And when there is no record matching on the table I want it to just insert the new record.
And I want the trigger to apply for every new record individually from oldest to newest by the VALID_FROM column being inserted.
I already tried this query, but the trigger applies to all the records being inserted at the same time so the VALID_UNTIL result for every record is '2099-12-31'
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_valid_until
ON cal.MA_COSTS
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE t
    SET t.VALID_UNTIL = i.VALID_FROM
    FROM cal.MA_COSTS t
    INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON t.ITEM_ID= i.ITEM_ID
        AND t.VALID_UNTIL = '2099-12-31'
        AND t.VALID_FROM < i.VALID_FROM;
END;

Here is some sample data as well
INSERT INTO cal.MA_COSTS (ITEM_ID, COST1, COST2, PRICE1, PRICE2, VALID_FROM)
VALUES
(2008209, 4062.7, 4062.7, 5803.85, 6732.47, '2024-12-01'),
(2008209, 4119.57, 4119.57, 5885.09, 6826.7, '2024-12-02'),
(2008209, 4150.85, 4150.85, 5929.78, 6878.54, '2024-12-06');


Are you sure about the table structure? Primary key can not be defined twice on the same table

Yes my primary key is a combination of both columns none of them are unique, but the combination of both is

perfect. Sample data and desired output will help us to help you

Please show also your INSERT query.

Here is some sample data
INSERT INTO cal.MA_COSTS (ITEM_ID, COST1, COST2, PRICE1, PRICE2, VALID_FROM)
VALUES
(2008209, 4062.7, 4062.7, 5803.85, 6732.47, '2024-12-01'),
(2008209, 4119.57, 4119.57, 5885.09, 6826.7, '2024-12-02'),
(2008209, 4150.85, 4150.85, 5929.78, 6878.54, '2024-12-06');


Before you go any further, change the datatype of your columns - DO NOT USE FLOAT for money! Float is an inaccurate datatype intended for scientific data... you need a precise datatype, you don't want to lose money due to the behaviour of float. Use something like decimal(18,2).

We need a complete [mre] i.e. sample data before insert, sample data to insert, desired results after insert.

Returning to the question from  @Sergey: Msg 8110 Level 16 State 0 Line 1 Cannot add multiple PRIMARY KEY constraints to table 'ma_costs'

Also I highly recommend only storing a valid from date per Item_Id - you do not need to store the valid to date, you can calculate it, and doing so makes your trigger far easier to write. After all I assume your usage is to be able to find the price at any given point of time? If so its very easy to write a query to obtain that ONLY using a valid from date. The valid to date is not necessary or even helpful.

Have you considered a Temporal Table, which supports this kind of ValidFrom/To automatically? Anyway, we need expected output, because I'm not really clear.

I like Dale K's idea of eliminating the VALID_UNTIL column and using the CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ...) pattern for looking up prices.
However, if that isn't an option, the following should satisfy your needs.
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_valid_until
ON MA_COSTS
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE tPrior
    SET VALID_UNTIL = i.VALID_FROM
    FROM inserted i
    CROSS APPLY (
        -- Locate immediately prior cost row for this item
        SELECT TOP 1 t.*
        FROM MA_COSTS t
        WHERE t.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
        AND t.VALID_FROM < i.VALID_FROM
        ORDER BY t.VALID_FROM DESC
    ) tPrior
    WHERE tPrior.VALID_UNTIL = '2099-12-31'
    --or perhaps: WHERE tPrior.VALID_UNTIL > i.VALID_FROM
END;

For each inserted row, the prior row is identified and updated as needed.
An index in MA_COSTS(ITEM_ID, VALID_FROM) is needed to support direct lookup of the related rows using an index seek. If (ITEM_ID, VALID_FROM) is the primary key, no separate index is needed.
If you might be inserting rows with VALID_FROM values in the middle of the existing range, a second update may be needed to set the VALID_UNTIL values for the newly added row(s).
...
    UPDATE tCurrent
    SET VALID_UNTIL = tNext.VALID_FROM
    FROM inserted i
    JOIN MA_COSTS tCurrent
        ON tCurrent.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
        AND tCurrent.VALID_FROM = i.VALID_FROM
    CROSS APPLY (
        -- Locate immediately following cost row for this item
        SELECT TOP 1 t.*
        FROM MA_COSTS t
        WHERE t.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
        AND t.VALID_FROM > i.VALID_FROM
        ORDER BY t.VALID_FROM
    ) tNext
    WHERE tCurrent.VALID_UNTIL > tNext.VALID_FROM

Note that the above does not handle updates or deletes that may require adjustments to other rows.
Sample results after multiple insert operations with rows presented in a mixed order:



ITEM_ID
COST1
COST2
PRICE1
PRICE2
VALID_FROM
VALID_UNTIL




2008209
4062.7
4062.7
5803.85
6732.47
2024-12-01
2024-12-02


2008209
4119.57
4119.57
5885.09
6826.7
2024-12-02
2024-12-03


2008209
3333.33
3333.33
3333.33
3333.33
2024-12-03
2024-12-04


2008209
4444.44
4444.44
4444.44
4444.44
2024-12-04
2024-12-05


2008209
5555.55
5555.55
5555.55
5555.55
2024-12-05
2024-12-06


2008209
4150.85
4150.85
5929.78
6878.54
2024-12-06
2024-12-07


2008209
7777.77
7777.77
7777.77
7777.77
2024-12-07
2024-12-08


2008209
8888.88
8888.88
8888.88
8888.88
2024-12-08
2024-12-09


2008209
9999.99
9999.99
9999.99
9999.99
2024-12-09
2099-12-31



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Great! I think this worked for me, I'll be runnig test with this trigger! Thank you!

For a more robust solution, don't store VALID_UNTIL because VALID_FROM is enough. When you need to obtain the prices for a given date just use the following query:
select top 1 *
from MA_COSTS
where ITEM_ID = @ItemId
and VALID_FROM <= @DateOfInterest
order by VALID_FROM desc;

There is no advantage in storing VALID_UNTIL - it just makes things more complicated.
And ensure you change the datatype of your columns - DO NOT USE FLOAT to store money! Float is an inaccurate datatype intended for scientific data... you need a precise datatype, you don't want to lose money due to the behaviour of float. Use something like decimal(18,2)

I mainly want to store VALID_UNTIL to cross reference my SALES table with this COSTS table, so I can get the costs of every sale in the range of VALID_FROM - VALID_UNTIL

You can calculate that in a similar manner to this query without storing it.

I have slightly corrected the description of the table. It's more consistent with your text.
Mainly - set default value for column VALID_UNTIL.
create table ma_costs(
  ITEM_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  COST1 FLOAT NOT NULL,
  COST2 FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRICE1 FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRICE2 FLOAT NOT NULL,
  VALID_FROM DATE NOT NULL , 
  VALID_UNTIL DATE default '2099-12-31'  NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(item_id,valid_from)
);
create index ix_ma_costs_item_id_valid_from on ma_costs(item_id,valid_from);

Your trigger works, when you insert 1 row in query. Then there is 1 row with the value valid_until='2099-12-31'. JOIN is correct
ON t.ITEM_ID= i.ITEM_ID
 AND t.VALID_UNTIL = '2099-12-31' AND t.VALID_FROM < i.VALID_FROM

When you insert batch, and default value for valid_until is '2099-12-31' INNER JOIN in trigger can not work correctly. There only 1 row in t match to all rows in i.
See example:
For test. Insert 1 row without trigger. Default for valid_until is correct.
INSERT INTO MA_COSTS (ITEM_ID, COST1, COST2, PRICE1, PRICE2, VALID_FROM)
VALUES
(2008201, 4062.71, 4062.71, 5803.81, 6732.41, '2024-10-01');
select * from ma_costs;




ITEM_ID
COST1
COST2
PRICE1
PRICE2
VALID_FROM
VALID_UNTIL




2008201
4062.71
4062.71
5803.81
6732.41
2024-10-01
2099-12-31



Your trigger:
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_valid_until
ON MA_COSTS
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE t
    SET t.VALID_UNTIL = i.VALID_FROM
    FROM MA_COSTS t
    INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON t.ITEM_ID= i.ITEM_ID
        AND t.VALID_UNTIL = '2099-12-31'
        AND t.VALID_FROM < i.VALID_FROM;
END;

Insert rows one by one (item_id=2008201).
INSERT INTO MA_COSTS (ITEM_ID, COST1, COST2, PRICE1, PRICE2, VALID_FROM)
VALUES (2008201, 4062.7, 4062.7, 5803.85, 6732.47, '2024-12-01');
INSERT INTO MA_COSTS (ITEM_ID, COST1, COST2, PRICE1, PRICE2, VALID_FROM)
VALUES (2008201, 4119.57, 4119.57, 5885.09, 6826.7, '2024-12-02');
INSERT INTO MA_COSTS (ITEM_ID, COST1, COST2, PRICE1, PRICE2, VALID_FROM)
VALUES (2008201, 4150.85, 4150.85, 5929.78, 6878.54, '2024-12-06');

Output is correct



ITEM_ID
COST1
COST2
PRICE1
PRICE2
VALID_FROM
VALID_UNTIL




2008201
4062.71
4062.71
5803.81
6732.41
2024-10-01
2024-12-01


2008201
4062.7
4062.7
5803.85
6732.47
2024-12-01
2024-12-02


2008201
4119.57
4119.57
5885.09
6826.7
2024-12-02
2024-12-06


2008201
4150.85
4150.85
5929.78
6878.54
2024-12-06
2099-12-31



Insert several rows simultaneously  (item_id=2008209)
INSERT INTO MA_COSTS (ITEM_ID, COST1, COST2, PRICE1, PRICE2, VALID_FROM)
VALUES
(2008209, 4062.7, 4062.7, 5803.85, 6732.47, '2024-11-01'),
(2008209, 4119.57, 4119.57, 5885.09, 6826.7, '2024-11-02'),
(2008209, 4150.85, 4150.85, 5929.78, 6878.54, '2024-11-06');




ITEM_ID
COST1
COST2
PRICE1
PRICE2
VALID_FROM
VALID_UNTIL




2008201
4062.71
4062.71
5803.81
6732.41
2024-10-01
2024-12-01


2008201
4062.7
4062.7
5803.85
6732.47
2024-12-01
2024-12-02


2008201
4119.57
4119.57
5885.09
6826.7
2024-12-02
2024-12-06


2008201
4150.85
4150.85
5929.78
6878.54
2024-12-06
2099-12-31


2008209
4062.7
4062.7
5803.85
6732.47
2024-11-01
2024-11-06


2008209
4119.57
4119.57
5885.09
6826.7
2024-11-02
2024-11-06


2008209
4150.85
4150.85
5929.78
6878.54
2024-11-06
2099-12-31



fiddle
My suggestion is
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_valid_until
ON MA_COSTS
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @nn bigint;
    set @nn=next value for sq_trigger_work_count; -- for test
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE t
    SET t.VALID_UNTIL = i.VALID_FROM
          -- log operation to column testValue
       ,t.testValue=concat('(',i.valid_from,'-',i.valid_until
                  ,':',t.valid_from,'-',t.valid_until
                  ,':',(select count(*) from ma_costs)
          ,')'   ) 
    FROM MA_COSTS t
    INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON t.ITEM_ID= i.ITEM_ID
      and t.valid_from=(select max(valid_from) from ma_costs t2 
                        where t2.item_id=i.item_id and  t2.valid_from<i.valid_from)

      ;
END;

Details see in example fiddle
